# How to simplify; assigning names of dataframe using substring? (R)

Tags: r

I have two folders: `data/ct1` `data/ct2`. In each folder I have 14 to 15 named csv files. (ex) ct1_01_examinee.csv, ct1_02_disease.csv etc...)

I want to drop the words that comes after "ct1_01_" or "ct1_02_" and use only "ct1_01" or "ct1_02", since the file names are long.

Here is my code:

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ExclusionTable)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# the HEXA cohort (1 of 3)
## ct1
flnames1<-list.files(path = "C:/Users/aaa/Documents/data/ct1", pattern = "\\.csv", full.names=TRUE)
df_list1<-lapply(flnames1, read.csv)

## ct2
flnames2<-list.files(path = "C:/Users/aaa/Documents/data/ct2", pattern = "\\.csv", full.names=TRUE)
df_list2<-lapply(flnames2, read.csv)

names(df_list1) <- gsub(".csv","",list.files("C:/Users/aaa/Documents/data/ct1",full.names = FALSE),fixed = TRUE)
ct1_01 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_01_examinee)
ct1_02 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_02_disease)
ct1_03 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_03_oper)
ct1_04 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_04_drug)
ct1_08 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_08_habit1)
ct1_09 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_09_habit2)
ct1_11 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_11_femd)
ct1_13 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_13_ffq)
ct1_13_1 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_13_ffqnutri)
ct1_14 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_14_anthropometry)
ct1_15 <- as.data.frame(df_list1$ct1_15_biochem)

names(df_list2) <- gsub(".csv","",list.files("C:/Users/aaa/Documents/data/ct2",full.names = FALSE),fixed = TRUE)
ct2_01 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_01_examinee)
ct2_02 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_02_disease)
ct2_04 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_04_drug)
ct2_08 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_07_habit1)
ct2_09 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_08_habit2)
ct2_11 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_10_femd)
ct2_12 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_12_ffq)
ct2_12_1 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_12_ffqnutri)
ct2_13 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_13_anthropometry)
ct2_14 <- as.data.frame(df_list2$ct2_14_biochem)

ct1_list <- list(
  ct1_01,
  ct1_02,
  ct1_03,
  ct1_04,
  ct1_08,
  ct1_09,
  ct1_11,
  ct1_13,
  ct1_13_1,
  ct1_14,
  ct1_15
)

ct2_list <- list(
  ct2_01,
  ct2_02,
  ct2_04,
  ct2_08,
  ct2_09,
  ct2_11,
  ct2_12,
  ct2_12_1,
  ct2_13,
  ct2_14
)

ct_list <- append(ct1_list, ct2_list)
ct <- join_all(ct_list, by = "RID", type = "inner", match = "first")# length(unique(ct$RID))

#Inclusion and Exclusion criteria
fu <- join_all(list(ct1_01, ct2_01), by = c('RID'), type = "inner", )
fu_loss <- ct1_01 %>% anti_join(ct2_01, by = ('RID'))
```

Since the code looks eerily redundant, I have tried expanding "str_sub" function:

```
## ct1
flnames1<-list.files(path = "C:/Users/aaa/Documents/data/ct1", pattern = "\\.csv", full.names=TRUE)
df_list1<-lapply(flnames1, read.csv) %>%
names(.) <- gsub(".csv","",list.files("C:/Users/aaa/Documents/data/ct1",full.names = FALSE),fixed = TRUE)

for (i in length(df_list1)){
str_sub(names(df_list1)[i], 0, 6) <- as.data.frame(df_list1$names(df_list1)[i])
}
```

but the above code gives:

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

how can I improve? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're trying to do in the for loop in your last block of code. The error (I think) is because `df_list1$names` isn't a function but you have the parentheses after it, implying that you're trying to feed it an argument. Are you just trying to abbreviate the names of `df_list1` and convert them all into data.frames?

Comment: @Ethan Bass yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. For example, ct1_15_biochem becomes ct1_15, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest converting to the data.frame in your initial call to lapply. Then you need to just shorten the names. You don't need a for loop or anything for reassigning the names because most of the string manipulation functions in R (including `substr` and `gsub`) are vectorized.

```
# read in list of csvs and convert them to dataframes
df_list1<-lapply(flnames1, function(x){
  as.data.frame(read.csv(x))
 })
# get first 6 letters of each name
names(df_list1) <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(flnames1)) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
```